# array allocation followed by memcpy or vector with reserve?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, memcpy

I have a byte array which i want to compress.(Size 400 byte on avg).I have two options.I keep an array of 400 byte and stuff bits in it.Finally say the compressed size is 300 byte so I use memcpy to copy those bytes to an array of size 300 and send.
Else I can keep a vector and reserve 400 byte and use push_back.(Here i can avoid the memcpy).
I get a huge number of arrays per second. So in a performance critical scenario which choice will give better performance?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to do. Say you have a vector and fill it with `push_back`. Do you use _that_ vector then? If you already have an array of 300 elements, then why you use `memcpy`?

Comment: If I got a huge number of arrays per second, I would personally prefer the `resize` method over `reserve`. It seems faster.

Comment: I have to send the compressed array.So i copy the bytes which are part of compressed data not the full array that I allocated to hold them (as I dont know the size apriori) @polfsol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it needs to be fast, you definitely don't want to `push_back` each individual byte one-at-a-time; you want to do a bulk transfer, like what `memcpy` does.  But you can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), which should be just as efficient.  For primitive types like `char` or `int`, using `std::vector` with `std::copy` is basically a layer on top of a raw array and `memcpy`.